# Get one of requested hidden input values,where the key is similar

Tags: jsf, request, hidden

**JSF:**

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputHidden id="promo" value="promo-motopair"/>
    <h:commandButton value="#{m.buy}" action="#{showProducts.buy}"/>
</h:form>


<h:form>
    <h:inputHidden id="promo" value="promo-northduck"/>
    <h:commandButton value="#{m.buy}" action="#{showProducts.buy}"/>
</h:form>
```

**Bean, where get clicked id:**

```
String promo = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("promo");
```

Can't get it because `id` is equal `promo`, but prepended with prefix, looks like `j_idt40:promo`

How to handle such situation?

I need get item by `key`. I suppose,that key(which is `id` in `inputhidden`) should be single. I should rely on `promo` value only.

Comment: @Ravi: this would in OP's case result in [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) HTML.

Comment: the main issue here that I see,that I use same id several times. From other side I can use `containsKey()` or `values()` method,but looks not gracefully IMHO

Comment: @BalusC, ya I did not see that there are two components with the same Id.

Comment: @Ravi: the whole question is about exactly that, how'd you miss that? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `<h:inputHidden>`. It's unsuitable for your particular functional requirement. Just use standard HTML `<input type="hidden">`.

```
<h:form>
    <input type="hidden" name="promo" value="promo-motopair"/>
    <h:commandButton value="#{m.buy}" action="#{showProducts.buy}"/>
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <input type="hidden" name="promo" value="promo-northduck"/>
    <h:commandButton value="#{m.buy}" action="#{showProducts.buy}"/>
</h:form>
```

It's in a request scoped bean by the way also available by just

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.promo}")
private String promo;
```

without the need to manually grab it from the request parameter map.

Comment: BalusC,hi .Thank you for hint,and the problem is showProducts bean is `SessionScoped`

Comment: Use `<f:viewParam name="promo" value="#{showProducts.promo}"/>` then. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for You can also just stick to the request parameter map grabbing approach :)

Comment: @BalusC: How about getting the component from ActionEvent and then getParent#findComponent("promo")?